# Need help in logrotation

Tags: unix, logrotate, log-rotation

I have custom logrotation as below..

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/apache
#
#
/var/log/apache/apache.log
{
        daily
        rotate 30
        size 1G
        compress
        missingok
        copytruncate
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s.log
}
```

here is the ls output.

```
ls -lrth /var/log/apache/apache.log*
-rw------- 1 root root 171M Oct 10 02:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696883462.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 121M Oct 10 05:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696894261.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 119M Oct 10 09:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696908661.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 143M Oct 10 13:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696923061.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 136M Oct 10 16:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696933861.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 132M Oct 10 19:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696944661.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 132M Oct 10 22:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696955461.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 161M Oct 11 02:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1696969861.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 145M Oct 11 06:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1696984261.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 137M Oct 11 11:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697002261.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 120M Oct 11 13:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697009461.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 118M Oct 11 15:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697016661.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 134M Oct 11 19:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697031061.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 967M Oct 11 20:52 apache.log
```

So here is the problem. I see **Oct 10 logs** in the rotated log file `apache.log-2023-10-11-1696969861.log.gz` and **Oct 9 logs** in `apache.log-2023-10-10-1696883462.log.gz`. I do not want that to happen. I want **Oct 10 logs** to be exclusively in same day log rotated files wihtout changing the above format.. say for e.g.  `apache.log-2023-10-10-***********.log.gz`. Could you guys please guide, how to achieve it.

Comment: you limited the size of the log to 1G which is the first limitation that meet in an or condition imho I would suggest that you try a size of 5G testwise

Comment: So If we try with 5G, will it exactly rotate at 12 AM midnight?

Comment: okay I explain more, you set a or condition. Either the limit of 5G or at daily. you have to try it. This means if the Filesiz is 5g,it will be rotating instantly. if its lower as 5g,it will rotate at the end of the day